# Calling jQuery function on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style jQuery search script that uses tabs for the user to define which search type they want to use. However, when the user searches for something and then selects a new search type (clicks on a tab) they have to go to the text box and press enter to submit their query again.

It was recommended for me to call the `loadurl()` function on click of one of the tabs but how can I do this and load the correct content for the correct tab? I hope you can understand what I'm trying to describe.

My current jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loadurl() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('results').html(results);
            }
        });
    }
    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
    });
    $('#type_search').click();
    $('input').keyup(function () {
        query = $(this).val();
        url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search Script';
        $('results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('results').hide();
        }
        loadurl();
    });
});
```

My current HTML code is:

```
<div id='nav'> 
<a id='type_search'>All</a> 
<a id='type_images'>Images</a> 
<a id='type_videos'>Videos</a> 
<a id='type_news'>News</a> 
<a id='type_social'>Social</a> 
</div>
<input type='text' autocomplete='off'>

<div id='results'></div>
```

Comment: You are not appending the hash `#` to your result div..`$('results')` should be `$('#results')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the `input` box `keyup` event whenever any tab is selected. If you want you can also check if currently selected tab is clicked do not do anything just return.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loadurl() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (results) {
                $('#results').html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    $('[id^=type_]').click(function () {
        type = this.id.replace('type_', '');
        $('[id^=type_]').removeClass('selected');
        $('#type_' + type).addClass('selected');
        $('input').trigger('keyup');
    });

    $('#type_search').click();

    $('input').keyup(function () {
        query = $(this).val();
        if(!query)
          return;
        url = '/' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        window.location.hash = '' + type + '/' + query + '/';
        document.title = $(this).val() + ' - My Search Script';
        $('#results').show();
        if (query == '') {
            window.location.hash = '';
            document.title = 'My Search Script';
            $('#results').hide();
        }
        loadurl();
    });

});
```

Comment: That check should be there in the input keyup handler.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, I have added the necessary condition.